# How to find name of a nodes type to create with python

Tags: python, node-editor

I would like to create a ColorRamp node, but I don't know how it is called internally.

```
import bpy

selection = bpy.context.object
currentMaterial = selection.active_material
currentMaterial.use_nodes = True
nodes = currentMaterial.node_tree.nodes
colorRamp = nodes.new(type = 'ShaderNodeColorRamp')
```

The 'ShaderNodeColorRamp' does not work, the string is wrong, how do I find it's correct name out?

[image]

When creating the node via the search menu, the info area only say:

```
bpy.ops.node.add_search(node_item='69')
```

Comment: I mean it's more to know how to get the name of any node.
So the duplicate helped only a bit.

Comment: Mostly agree. Hence the title edit... please clean up the question code , eg add imports etc to make minimal running example   so wrong type name is the error and  will reopen. Another way is via python console after adding node, but in that case may as well enable python tooltips as shown.

Comment: Re your last edit, think you are confusing the python console with the info area, plus you are adding via search, not as below directly via menu.

Comment: But the python console does not say anything, it is just almost blank for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `ShaderNodeValToRGB`.

Turn on *Python Tooltips* under *Edit > Preferences > Interface*. Then go to the Shader Editor and hover over a node in the *Add* menu to see a tooltip with the name.

[image: Hovering over ColorRamp]

Comment: Out of interest, are you able to screenshot the tooltips directly?  For me have to make a gif then screenshot the tip from gif, since on linux the print screen is sans tooltip.

Comment: Yeah, it's caught no problem. I use `scrot` for screenshooting.

Comment: Or Lightshot on GitHub

Answer (score 3):

*To answer comments under question, In addition to using the tooltips, as demonstrated in accepted answer.*

**Python console.**

*Use the python console to directly input python code and get instant feedback. In example below, typing the variable `mat` into console, echos the representation of its value.  IMO this is one of the strengths of a scripting language like python, can get feedback without compiling*

In this example looking at the active material of the active object

```
>>> mat = C.object.active_material
>>> mat
bpy.data.materials['Material']

>>> for n in mat.node_tree.nodes:
...     n.name, n.type, n.__class__.__name__
...     
('Principled BSDF', 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED', 'ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
('Material Output', 'OUTPUT_MATERIAL', 'ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')
('ColorRamp', 'VALTORGB', 'ShaderNodeValToRGB')
```

the last node listed named `"ColorRamp"`  with enumerated type `'VALTORGB'` is an instance of class `bpy.types.ShaderNodeValToRGB`

Could iterate over all materials

```
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if mat.use_nodes:
         <as above>
```

**The Info window.**

If the node is added as shown in accepted answer (not via the search for nodes menu) then

[image]

```
bpy.ops.node.add_node(type='ShaderNodeValToRGB')
```

as described in accepted answer.